# Aspose.slides python error convert a pdf to PowerPoint ( ppt )

Tags: python, django, pdf, powerpoint, aspose

I want to convert a pdf to PowerPoint ( ppt ) using the Aspose library with python and I got this error below:

```
pres.slides.add_from_pdf(pdfPath)
RuntimeError: Proxy error╗): Bad state (unknown compression
 method (0x47))
```

the code I wrote to convert pdf to ppt is the following :

```
def pdf2ppt(pdfPath, pptPath):
    with slides.Presentation() as pres:
        pres.slides.remove_at(0)
        pres.slides.add_from_pdf(pdfPath)
        pres.save(pptPath, slides.export.SaveFormat.PPTX)
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: We need more details on the issue to help you properly: the PDF file, Aspose.Slides version you used, OS version on which the conversion was performed. I am working at Aspose as a Support Developer and will be glad to help you.

Comment: Hello Andrey! , I have figured out the issue, the pdf I wanted to convert contains multiple pages while the code can only convert add one page of pdf at a time, thank you.